# Lisp acessing value (new to Lisp)

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and don't know how to access the `:DIM` value!  Here's the code:

```
(defstruct peca 
  dim 
  val)

(setf exemple #S(PECA :DIM 2 :VAL 1))
```

How can I get the value of `:DIM` from `exemple`?
When I try `exemple-dim` it says `variable -DIM has no value`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro `defstruct` defines reader functions, among other things. The default names for these are of the form *structname-slotname*, in your case giving `peca-dim` and `peca-val`.

There is further information in the [HyperSpec, here.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm)

Comment: jwmc has answered the direct question of how you access those values.  You should know that if you don't like the default style of "classname + hyphen + slot-name", you can use the :conc-name option to specify something nicer for the initial portion (usually something shorter).  Now, I would recommend against typing #S(...) yourself.  Lisp prints it that way, but you should use the automatically defined (make-peca :dim ... :val ...) constructor instead.